# WSO2 API manager support for HTTP

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm trying to confirm a few things about the WSO2 API manager.

1. It can support pass through of HTTP and support a response from a back end HTTP server of type 206 partial content & range request or chanced responses. I believe the Pass through transport can do this but not 100% sure
2. Can session state be maintained in the above scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Normally session details of TCP level is been handled by the implementation by default however we would like to know what exactly you mean by maintaining a session state here? Can you please elaborate more on your exact requirement and is there any specific scenario you are trying out here referring maintaining a session state?